# Close soft keyboard after dialog on Samsung devices

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have a dialog containing an EditText (`inputType="number"`). After the dialog is dismissed i would like to hide the keyboard, which is opened if the EditText of the dialog was in Focus at some point.

Now the thing is that i have an approach that works (at least on some Nexus Devices), except for Samsung Devices (S2, S3 at least).

```
final InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

On other devices the keyboard (only numbers) closes after the dialog.
On Samsung devices the keyboard just changes to a keyboard with all the letters (`inputType="text")`, instead of the keyboard for `inputType="numbers"`. I want it to close/hide instead.

I can not do something like
`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)`
for the Activity in the background, because i need a keyboard there as well.

Does anyone know how to handle this Samsung specific problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: Whoa! This worked and the answer came really fast, thank you a lot! I searched a lot and everyone came up with the same answers that did not work. I have to wait 3 minutes and then i can mark this answer as the right one :)

Comment: this doesn't help, because it will make the keyboard appear if the keyboard wasn't visible

Answer (score 1):

I have no Samsung device to test my code, but I'm using the WindowToken from the EditText to hide the SoftKeyboard.
My Code looks like this:

```
View focused = getCurrentFocus();
if (focused != null) {
    InputMethodManager iM = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    iM.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focused.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: I have tried this too, hideSoftInputFromWindow does never work like it should in my context. Thanks for answering!